# Magic commas in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, split

I am writing a Sudoku validator as a practice problem. I import an 81 digit board in a single line delimited by a single space as a string. When I print the string at line 4, there are no commas separating the digits in my input. At line 14 I use the split method to split it into an array that should be 81 indexes long. When I test it by printing the array at line 20, the indexes between the digits have been populated by commas. I do not know where these magic commas have come from, it must be a result of the split method since my input does not contain any commas. Can anyone explain what is happening? Here is the JS script:

```
function import1() {
    var board = prompt("Please enter a board");
    if (board != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "board entered: " + board + "\n";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Invalid entry\n";
    }

    parseMe(board);
}

function parseMe(board) {

    var boardArray = String(board.split(" "));

    var toPrint = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < boardArray.length; j++) {
        toPrint += boardArray[j];
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "test" + toPrint;


    var board2D = [
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
    ];

    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < board2D.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < board2D.length; j++) {
            board2D[i][j] = boardArray[counter];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter != 81) {

     document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Invalid entry, should be 81 total digits\n";
    }
    printBoard(board2D);
}

function printBoard(board) {
    var toPrint = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
         toPrint += board[i][j] + " ";
        }
        toPrint += "\n";
    }
    document.getElementById("printBoard").innerHTML = toPrint;
}
```

I can provide the webpage I'm writing to if anyone wants to see it, but I don't think it matters.

Here is what the output looks like:

board entered: 5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2 6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8 1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7 8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3 4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1 7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6 9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4 2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5 3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9

test5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2,6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8,1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7,8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3,4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1,7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6,9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4,2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5,3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9

Comment: `boardArray` is not an array; it's a string (since you wrap it in `String()`). That causes it to use `Array.prototype.toString`, which uses a comma by default.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you want `boardArray` to actually _be_ an **Array** you don't want to wrap it in `String()` -- `let boardArray = board.split(' ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting from `board.split(" ")` (an array) to a string, commas will be inserted. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)), and an example below:

```js
var test = ['1', '2', '3'];

console.log(test[0], test[1]);

var testAsString = String(test);

console.log(testAsString[0], testAsString[1]);
```

You should not need to convert this back from the array, just access the elements normally.

```js
function import1() {
    var board = prompt("Please enter a board");
    if (board != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "board entered: " + board + "\n";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Invalid entry\n";
    }

    parseMe(board);
}

function parseMe(board) {

    var boardArray = board.split(" ");

    var toPrint = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < boardArray.length; j++) {
        toPrint += boardArray[j];
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "test" + toPrint;


    var board2D = [
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
    ];

    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < board2D.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < board2D.length; j++) {
            board2D[i][j] = boardArray[counter];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter != 81) {
     document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Invalid entry, should be 81 total digits\n";
    }
    printBoard(board2D);
}

function printBoard(board) {
    var toPrint = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
         toPrint += board[i][j] + " ";
        }
        toPrint += "\n";
    }
    document.getElementById("printBoard").innerHTML = toPrint;
}

import1();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="printBoard"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: IMO, do your check at the beginning of `parseMe` to see if it's 81. ie. `if (boardArray.length != 81) { /* write error */ return; }`

Answer (score 0):

When you do this :

```
String(board.split(" "));

for (var j = 0; j < boardArray.length; j++) {
    toPrint += boardArray[j];
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "test" + toPrint;
```

you need to remember that `String(board.split(" "));` is turning an array into a string, and this will cause to include some commas for the representation.

So when you iterate, you iterate over the characters of the string, and just copy it, with the commas.

You just don't need to transform this into a string !